# Filtering table results with drop down menu in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filter, drop-down-menu

Created a drop down menu that is supposed to work as a filter. I am filtering with enum values so not sure how to make it work. The view + route are working fine. When the button is pressed the URL changes and adds the selected enum value `/dropdown?filter_status=inactive`. But the results are not filtered.

View:

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-start">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="{{ route('dropdownView') }}" method="GET">
                <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                <span>
                <select class="mb-2" name="filter_status" >
                <option value="Status" disabled selected>Status</option>
                @foreach ($enumoption as $status)
                   <option value="{{ $status }}">{{$status}}</option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ms-1 mb-1">Filter</button>
                </span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Route:

```
Route::get("/dropdown", [CompetitionController::class, 'index'])->name('dropdownView');
```

Controller(`getPossibleEnumValues` is the function I am using in my model to get the enum values)

```
$enumoption = Competition::getPossibleEnumValues('competitions','status');
```

EDIT:

```
public static function getPossibleEnumValues($table, $column) {
      $type = DB::select(DB::raw("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table WHERE Field = '{$column}'"))[0]->Type ;
      preg_match('/^enum\((.*)\)$/', $type, $matches);
      $enum = array();
      foreach( explode(',', $matches[1]) as $value )
      {
        $v = trim( $value, "'" );
        $enum = Arr::add($enum, $v, $v);
      }
      return $enum;
    }
```

Comment: can you posted the full code of method ``getPossibleEnumValues``?

Comment: What's the result of ``$enumoption``?